# Memory Management Advice

Tags: objective-c

In my root view, I have a tableview with three rows. When I click either row, it will present a new view and then I can press the back button that is automatically created by my nav controller. My problem arises when I try to click a row that has already been chosen before. I get an EXC BAD ACCESS error message. I think this is all the code that is neccessary:

```
 - (void)dealloc
 {
     self.rowChosenArray = nil;
     self.rootChoicesArray = nil;
     self.customImage = nil;
     self.rootTableView = nil;
     [super dealloc];
 }

 - (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.rootChoicesArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"",@"See Today's  Deals!", @"My Purchased Deals", @"Personal Settings", nil] autorelease];

    self.rowChosenArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"", nil] autorelease];

    DealsViewController *dealsViewController = [[DealsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DealsViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.rowChosenArray addObject:dealsViewController];
    [dealsViewController release];

    PurchasedDealsViewController *purchasedDealsViewController = [[PurchasedDealsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PurchasedDealsViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.rowChosenArray addObject:purchasedDealsViewController];
    [purchasedDealsViewController release];

    SettingsViewController *settingsViewController = [[SettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SettingsViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.rowChosenArray addObject:settingsViewController];
    [settingsViewController release];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UIViewController *targetViewController = [rowChosenArray objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:targetViewController animated:YES];
[targetViewController release];
}
```

I am still unfamiliar where/when to release/set objects to nil (all four of my objects have the retain property in the header file.

Thank you in advance for the help, let me know if there is anything else you may need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Before you add an element into an array, you alloc it, but release it once it is added - so there is no leak;
2. You never need to release the elements in the array, because they will be released at the time when you release the array itself.

Answer (score 1):

You are over-releasing `targetViewController` in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`. You get a non-owning reference through `objectAtIndex:` (which means that you are not responsible for that reference) and may not release that reference. So just remove `[targetViewController release];` and everything's fine.

The rule is like this: you may *only* release a reference if you either `retain`ed it or got it through a method whose name:

- is or starts with `alloc`, `copy` or `mutableCopy`
- starts with `new`

Answer (score 0):

also you have some leaks here, if you retain in `viewDidLoad` you should release/nil in `viewDidUnload` and in `dealloc`